# How can I split a raw buffer of uint8 I420 video data into YUV pointers?

Tags: c++, video-streaming, video-processing

I have a raw uint8 pointer to a buffer containing I420 formatted video data, and a buffer size.  I also know the frame width / height. I want to feed the data into a library which can create video frames via this function signature:

```
Copy(int width, int height,
        const uint8_t* data_y, int stride_y,
        const uint8_t* data_u, int stride_u,
        const uint8_t* data_v, int stride_v)
```

Is there some simple pointer arithmetic to resolve this?

Comment: Well, normally the Y plane comes in its entirety first, so you'd want a pointer to the start of your buffer and a stride of one. Then the V plane starts half way through the buffer and has a stride of one. Then U plane starts 3/4 of the way through also with stride of 1. Maybe. It could be that the stride must be the image width for Y and image width/2 for U and V.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much!  This is what I was hoping for.  Do you know of any "official" docs on such things that I might reference?

Comment: I normally refer to **fourcc**, here https://www.fourcc.org/yuv/

Comment: Thanks again! That site looks to be very informative!

Comment: Pleasure. Did you get it working?

Comment: Not yet.  I have some notable work to get my source "connected" to my destination, as far as my program structure goes.  I expect I'll get to test this concretely by some point tomorrow.  I'll definitely post an update at that point!

Comment: Thanks again for all the info! (i.e. the posted answer).  I have most of my design modifications in place, I'm just working on a circular buffer/semaphore situation now to get my data processed across producer/consumer in alternate threads.  Once my consumer can finally access the frame data, I'll be able to test this pointer math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best site I know for describing the various YUV and RGB video formats is FOURCC - the YUV descriptions are [here](https://www.fourcc.org/yuv/).

The I420 format you refer to is described [here](https://www.fourcc.org/yuv-i420/). That means that your raw data will be organised like this:

- Y plane, of H x W bytes, with a line stride of W bytes
- U plane, of H/2 x W/2 bytes, with a line stride of W/2 bytes
- V plane, of H/2 x W/2 bytes, with a line stride of W/2 bytes

I find `ffmpeg` is the very best tool for generating YUV data to encode into and decode out of your own software. Here are some tips for working with `ffmpeg` and raw YUV.

---

You can get a list of the pixel formats it supports with:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts
```

So, to find yours, I looked for something with 420 in it:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts | grep 420p
IO... yuv420p                3             12      8-8-8
```

so I know I need `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to encode or decode your data. I can also get a decent description of how that is laid out by checking the `ffmpeg` source [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/pixfmt.h). The 12 above means 12 bits per pixel.

---

Then I wanted to:

- generate a sample I420 frame with `ffmpeg`
- split it apart with `dd` and extract the Y, U and V channels with **IMageMagick**
- recombine the Y, U and V channels with **ImageMagick**
- recombine the Y, U and V channels with `ffmpeg`

so I made the following `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################################################
# User-editable values
################################################################################
# Define WIDTH and HEIGHT of the frame we want to generate...
# ... so we are consistent all the way through
W=640
H=480
PIX_FMT="yuv420p"

################################################################################
# Derived values - do not edit
################################################################################
BASENAME="${PIX_FMT}-${W}x${H}"
FILENAME="${BASENAME}.raw"
PNGNAME="${BASENAME}.png"
UVW=$((W/2))           # width of U plane, same as V plane
UVH=$((H/2))           # height of U plane, same as V plane
YBYTES=$((H*W))        # bytes in Y plane
UBYTES=$((UVW*UVH))    # bytes in U plane, same as in V plane

# Generate a sample frame
echo "Generating sample: ${FILENAME}, and viewable PNG equivalent: ${PNGNAME}"
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=${W}x${H}:rate=1:duration=1 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt "$PIX_FMT" -f image2pipe -  > "$FILENAME"
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=${W}x${H}:rate=1:duration=1 "$PNGNAME"

# Check its size in bytes
ls -l "$FILENAME"

# Extract Y plane from sample into "Y.png" using ImageMagick
echo "Extracting Y plane into Y.png"
dd if="$FILENAME" bs=$YBYTES count=1 | magick -depth 8 -size ${W}x${H} gray:- Y.png

# Extract U plane from sample into "U.png" using ImageMagick
echo "Extracting U plane into U.png"
dd if="$FILENAME" bs=1 skip=$YBYTES count=$UBYTES | magick -depth 8 -size ${UVW}x${UVH} gray:- U.png

# Extract V plane from sample into "V.png" using ImageMagick
echo "Extracting V plane into V.png"
dd if="$FILENAME" bs=1 skip=$((YBYTES+UBYTES)) count=$UBYTES | magick -depth 8 -size ${UVW}x${UVH} gray:- V.png

# Recombine with ImageMagick
echo "Combining Y.png, U.png, V.png into result.png"
magick Y.png \( U.png v.png -resize 200% \) -set colorspace YUV -combine result.png

# Create a PNG from the YUV420p raw data just the same with 'ffmpeg'
echo "Create PNG from the YUV420p raw data as 'extracted.png'" 
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -video_size 640x480 -pixel_format yuv420p -i - extracted.png < "$FILENAME"
```

That creates this image as PNG and as I420 data for you to test with:

[image]

and these Y, U and V planes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got my video feed working almost perfectly now! The only matter I have left to resolve is a strange frame rate issue, but that's entirely unrelated to this part of the story! Thanks again for all the info, Mark! The formulas here worked right out of the gate for me, once I could get to those details.

Comment: Along the way here, a colleague of mine pointed me to this awesome online tool: https://rawpixels.net/.  You may find that helpful in your endeavors.